# Is there a way to replace a string in a text without spaces?

Tags: javascript, string, web

Is there a way to replace something like this:

```
testHoraciotestHellotest
```

And replace the 'test' word via javascript, I've tried with the `.replace()` function but it didn't work

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Please edit your question and add what you've tried and how it didn't work

Comment: Instead of just saying "it didn't work", please share your code to show us what didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple.

```js
var str = "testHoraciotestHellotest";
var res = str.replace("test", "test1");
console.log(res);
```

If you want to replace all occurances of 'test' rather than just one,  use the following trick instead:

`var res = str.split("test").join ("test1");`

Comment: Only replaces the first instance of `test`.

Comment: @nicovank, edited my answer to include that option too. Thanks for your review and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

`str.replace()` also accepts regular expressions, so you can use `/test/g` to match all instances of 'test' in the string.

```js
var str = "testHoraciotestHellotest";
var res = str.replace(/test/g, "replaced");
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

use g to make a global replace to the string

```js
var str = "testHoraciotestHellotest";
var res = str.replace(/test/g, "word");
console.log(res);
```